# Smart view with static IP address?

Tags: networking, android, home-networking, chromecast

As a programmer, it sounds extremely simple to use something with a static IP address.
But unfortunately, the android smart view is "user friendly" and not "programmer-friendly".

#### What I want:

Cast the Android phone screen to my Chromecast Built-In Android TV Box.

#### The problem:

Smart view only scans the network of the phone (192.168.2.0/24) and this is why it will never find my Chromecast (192.168.1.5).

#### My network:

- 192.168.1.0/24 Ethernet devices
- 192.168.2.0/24 Wifi devices
- 192.168.2.17 My phone
- 192.168.1.5 Chromecast

I can ping from my phone to my Chromecast. I don't want to connect my Chromecast to the Wi-Fi, because it is slow.

#### How is it possible to use smart-view with a static IP address?

#### Or do you know some way to solve my problem?

It is also a possible solution if you know an app that can be installed on the phone and Android TV. Then I could use the "App smart-view" instead of the official smart view.

Comment: It is most certainly not scanning the network. Instead, it uses either multicast or maybe broadcast. You need to organize your network accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Would it fix the problem if I change the subnet masks of both networks to /16?

Comment: I have a DMZ on network 192.168.3.0/24 and I don't want to make my network insecure.

Comment: @Alwin07 I recommend making Ethernet and Wi-Fi a single LAN (a single broadcast/multicast domain and a single IP subnet). You probably don't have 250+ devices, so it can be a single /24.

Comment: @Stiff I already tried this, but it slows significantly down the internet speed of my PC. With 2 networks I have 300 Mbps download speed and with one network only 200 Mbps (even with higher router priority).